# Turn off SSL Django/Python server (Heroku)

Tags: python, django, ssl, heroku

How do I turn off SSL on a python (django) heroku app? No answers here on SO. Need to do POSTs from other websites, can only do that with http

Comment: What do you mean by posts can only be done with http?

Comment: cross origin problem (need referal thing in header)

Answer (score 0):

You can not turn off SSL.  It is on by default https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/3/announcing_better_ssl_for_your_app

To do a POST to a different domain/port/protocol you are running into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.

This SO answer details out the methods on bypassing same origin policy.  [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)